# ASIHTTPRequest Cache cannot be expired

Tags: objective-c, xml, caching, asihttprequest

I would like to set a cache with 60-second expiry. The xml file is successfully cached but the cache is kept using after the time expired even when the server updated data. Therefore, I would like to figure out what mistakes I did and seek for any solutions to fix it.

The code I write for sending a async http request:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] setShouldRespectCacheControlHeaders:NO];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

[request setSecondsToCache:60];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy | ASIAskServerIfModifiedWhenStaleCachePolicy];

[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30];

[[self queue] addOperation:request];
```

The code I write for receiving the request:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    BOOL success = [request didUseCachedResponse];
    NSLog(@"Success is %@\n", (success ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    NSData *data = [request responseData];
}
```

This is the header of the xml:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/xml;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 15 Apr 2013 08:49:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8b mod_jk/1.2.26 PHP/5.2.5
Set-Cookie:Expires=Mon, 15-Apr-2013 08:50:29 GMT;
```

This is the .cachedheaders file I find in /iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/XXX/Library/Caches/ASIHTTPRequestCache/PermanentStore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Connection</key>
<string>Keep-Alive</string>
<key>Content-Length</key>
<string>9296</string>
<key>Content-Type</key>
<string>application/xml;charset=utf-8</string>
<key>Date</key>
<string>Fri, 12 Apr 2013 09:49:33 GMT</string>
<key>Keep-Alive</key>
<string>timeout=5, max=99</string>
<key>Server</key>
<string>Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8b mod_jk/1.2.26 PHP/5.2.5</string>
<key>Set-Cookie</key>
<string>Expires=Fri, 12-Apr-2013 09:50:04 GMT;</string>
<key>X-ASIHTTPRequest-Expires</key>
<real>1365989738.766006</real>
<key>X-ASIHTTPRequest-Response-Status-Code</key>
<integer>200</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by reading this post.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/asihttprequest/Z0XRuBlZBSY

We have to amend codes in ASIDownloadCache.

I believe that this is a bug of ASIHTTPRequest.